# Use of having in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Please consider this sentence, "No change in schedule other than having Kelvin introducing you to the audience".

I already know Kelvin will be present. So do we need "having" in the above sentence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the word "having" means "assigning"

That is the only change in the schedule; except it should read "having Kelvin introduce" not "introducing."